# In episode 10 season 1 of Mad Men, how did Pete find out that Roger was in the hospital?

Tags: mad-men

The title says it all. There's a point in the episode near the end where Pete meets Don in the hospital to ask about "what happened", possibly indicating that he only heard that something was wrong, but not specifically about Roger.

How exactly did he find out about this information? There's very little chance that Don contacted him. The only thing I can think of is that he went back to the office to get something and saw Bert and Joan there and questioned what they were doing.

I know the point of not revealing how he found out is to emphasize how Pete is sort of mischievous and just finds out information in sly or underhanded ways, but I need a logical reason as to how he found out.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The heart attack had become fairly widespread knowledge by the time of the scene where Pete shows up at the hospital.

From the scene's plot summary in [its Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_Weekend_(Mad_Men)):

> Joan is notified of Roger's heart attack by Bert. She meets him at the
>   offices to write a telegram informing their clients of what has
>   happened... Pete arrives at the hospital just in time for Don and him
>   to see a highly persuasive TV ad...

*With Bert and Joan informing clients, it's safe to assume Bert (perhaps with Joan) has also informed Pete*, who services the clients (Bert and Joan wouldn't blindside Pete by telling the clients and not telling him).

If the question becomes *how did Bert find out?* -- I don't think it's shown, but *I presume Don informed Bert* out of deference to Bert's role as head of the firm who needs to know about an incident like that.

Comment: I guess I assumed beforehand that _clients_ only included the companies Sterling-Cooper had as clients, but it doesn't make much sense that they wouldn't have contacted the employees as well. Do you suppose there's any interesting reason for why _only_ Pete showed up?

Comment: I'm not sure Bert and Joan would have taken the time to tell all employees right away, but I think they would have told Pete, given his role with clients and his increasing importance to the firm. As to why only Pete showed up, I think he was one of the few employees who ranked high enough for a visit to make sense.